# Coplanar set in metric space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $(\Bbb M,d)$ be a metric space.

Give three points $X,$ $Y,$ $Z$ in $\Bbb M$ such that they satify one of the following conditions

$i)\ d(X,Y)+d(Y,Z)=d(X,Z),$

$ii)\ d(Y,Z)+d(Z,X)=d(Y,X),$

$iii)\ d(Z,X)+d(X,Y)=d(Z,Y),$

then we call $X,$ $Y,$ $Z$ are collinear, denote by ${\rm Col}(X,Y,Z).$

Give three points not collinear $A,$ $B,$ $C$ in $\Bbb M.$ $P$ is a point in $\Bbb M,$ assume that there always exists two points $E,$ $F$ in $\Bbb M$ such that

$${\rm Col}(C,A,E),\ {\rm Col}(P,B,E),\ {\rm Col}(A,B,F),\ {\rm Col}(P,C,F).$$

> **My question.** Does there always exist point $D\in\Bbb M$ such that
>   $${\rm Col}(B,C,D),\ {\rm Col}(P,A,D).$$

If the answer is yes, we can define the set $\{A,B,C,P\}$ as a coplanar set of $\Bbb M.$

Comment: This would be clarified by: 1) calling the relation betweenness ($Bet$) rather than collinearity ($Col$), 2) standardizing the text after the grey box (perhaps with replacements "yes. We" -> "yes, we" and "is a" -> "as a"), and 3) providing a diagram (which would probably show at least one mis-ordered triple).  As it stands, I'm not sure the hypotheses are ever satisfied.

Comment: So $\rm{Col}(X,Y,Z)$ and $\rm{Col}(X,Z,Y)$ are not the same?

Comment: This now assumes that for any $A,B,C,P$, there is a point $F$ on both line $AB$ and line $CP$.  So by a simple permutation of variables, there is always a point $D$ on both line $BC$ and line $PA$.  If I understand this all correctly, this is too trivial for a post either here or at MathStackExchange.

Comment: I hope the answer is yes. I think that if we can define four coplanar points in a metric space, we can work in some other problems. Sorry if this is really trivial.

Comment: Please see an application of coplanar set here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304451/euler-line-in-metric-space

Comment: Take 4 generic points $A,B,C,P$ in the plane, so $E,F,D$ exist and are unique. Now consider $M$ the plane minus $\{D\}$ to get a counterexample.