# Euler line in metric space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

If the answer about my question here is "yes" [Coplanar set in metric space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304421/coplanar-set-in-metric-space).

We shall have the concept of four coplanar points in metric space $(\Bbb M,d).$ I propose an idea about Euler line in metric space $(\Bbb M,d).$

As in above link, we define collinear points as following

Give three points $X,$ $Y,$ $Z$ in $\Bbb M$ such that they satify one of the following conditions

$i)\ d(X,Y)+d(Y,Z)=d(X,Z),$

$ii)\ d(Y,Z)+d(Z,X)=d(Y,X),$

$iii)\ d(Z,X)+d(X,Y)=d(Z,Y),$

then we call $X,$ $Y,$ $Z$ are collinear, denote by ${\rm Col}(X,Y,Z).$

Given three not collinear point $A,$ $B,$ $C$ in $\Bbb M.$

Define point $O$ such that $\begin{cases}d(O,A)=d(O,B)=d(O,C)\\ \{A,\ B,\ C,\ O\} \ \text{are coplanar.} \end{cases}$

Define point $H$ such that $\begin{cases}d^2(H,A)-d^2(H,B)=d^2(C,A)-d^2(C,B)\\ d^2(H,A)-d^2(H,C)=d^2(B,A)-d^2(B,C)\\ \{A,\ B,\ C,\ H\} \ \text{are coplanar.} \end{cases}$

Define point $G$ such that $d^2(G,A)+d^2(G,B)+d^2(G,C)=\frac{d^2(A,B)+d^2(B,C)+d^2(C,A)}{3}.$

> **My question.** Can we assert ${\rm Col}(H,G,O)?$

If the question is "yes", we can get the concept of Euler in metric space.

Comment: How to get this ideas? very nice.